# How to Run Annotation Processor without compiling sources using javac (Java 8 can't use Apt)

Tags: java, annotations, java-8, javac, annotation-processing

How can i Run Annotation Processor without compiling sources using javac (Java 8 can't use Apt)?

Is there any parameter for javac that could run only annotation processing without compiling all files?

What i want to do by javac:

- Just find annotated elements and process them using defined annotation processor using `-processor` flag
- do **not** compile any source that doesn't have any annotation

Because i want do this on Java 8 it's impossible to use Apt for this task? Or maybe it is?

Comment: `apt` also always compiled the sources. The only effect of `-nocompile` was that the compiled class files were not stored on the hard drive.

Comment: ok i didnt knows that but in javac this option is not available. Is there something different with same functionality or close functionality?

Comment: Maybe `-proc:only` comes close to it but I haven’t tried.

Answer (score 6):

The `apt` tool is not available in Java 8.  Based on what is said [here](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/117), porting `apt` to Java 8 would not be straight-forward.

According to the `javac` [manual entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javac.html):

> -proc: [none, only]
>
> Controls whether annotation processing and compilation are done. `-proc:none` means that compilation takes place without annotation processing. **`-proc:only` means that only annotation processing is done, without any subsequent compilation.**

It *sounds like* `-proc:only` would do what you want to do.  If not, then you would need to look for a 3rd-party tool, or develop a tool yourself.