# How do I run annotation processing via maven 3.3?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, dagger

For years, we've been running the maven-processor-plugin as a separate goal (using `proc:none` on maven-compiler-plugin).  We are *finally* upgrading from maven 3.0.5 to the latest 3.3.3, and I see that the maven-processor-plugin basically looks dead.  As far I a can tell, it has not been migrated out of google code.

We're using annotation processing primarily to generate dagger classes.  I can't remember the reasons, but at the time (in dagger-1), we got the impression it is better to do this during `generate-sources` and `generate-test-sources` phases rather than during the `compile` and `test-compile`, which is why we used the maven-processor-plugin to begin with.  Note that we want it all to play nicely in eclipse/m2e as well.

Is there a new, better way to run annotation processing from maven that is eclipse-friendly?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `maven-compiler-plugin` for annotation processing because the functionality exists in `javac`.  To do annotation processing and regular compilation in separate phases, you can do multiple executions of the plugin, one with [annotation processing turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798154/how-to-run-annotation-processor-without-compiling-sources-using-javac-java-8-ca), the other with it turned off.  The configuration for that is as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>process-annotations</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-proc:only</arg>
                    <arg>-processor</arg>
                    <arg>MyAnnotationProcessor</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id> <!-- using an id of default-compile will override the default execution -->
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-proc:none</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I upgraded to 3.6.0 and found that I had to remove the -proc:none argument for the compile phase of my annotations weren't compiled. Do you know of a change to another phase that would have removed the annotation class compilations? See my question (and pom) at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49160582/maven-compiler-plugin-3-6-0-doesnt-compile-generated-sources-from-annotations

Comment: Is `MyAnnotationProcessor` a fully qualified name (as in package + class name)?